# How to formatting a text in cell within XLSX file using Win32::OLE module in perl language

Tags: perl

I am trying to write an existing XLSX file using the win32::OLE module.I want to insert the values cell by cell. I would also like to format the cell (font, colour, alignment etc). my requirement is to use win32::OLE module only,can you please suggest me which method i have to use,thanks in advance....

```
**formatstring.pl**

use strict;
use warnings;
use win32::OLE;
our $Excel1 = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');
our $Workbook1= $Excel1->Workbooks->Open($outputfilepath);
my $sheet1 = $Workbook1->Worksheets(1);
our $RowCount=$sheet1->Usedrange->Rows->{Count};
 my $g_DS_TestCaseID="sd123";  
print "RowCount of outputfile: $RowCount";
$sheet1->Cells($RowCount+1,1)->{value}=$g_DS_TestCaseID;#here i want to format the text as bold with colorindex as green
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this a long, long time ago. This isn't really an answer, but a pointer:

Try doing it in Excel while recording a macro. Most times the methods and values are available without change over the COM interface. The recorded Macro gives you at least pointers for the direction in which to look, often times it gives you the exact methods/variables you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can check msdn, they have the answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff846982(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
our $Excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application');

$Excel->{'Visible'} = 1;
$Excel->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;
our $Workbook = $Excel->Workbooks->Open("$Bin/Test.xls");
my $Sheet = $Workbook->Worksheets(1);


$Sheet->Range("A2")->{Font}->{Bold} = 1;
$Sheet->Range("A2")->{Interior}->{ColorIndex} = 36;
```